# Ubuntu 20.04 does not stay in sleep

Tags: 20.04, suspend

When I click sleep  or `sudo systemctl suspend`, it seems to power down, screen turns dark for about 2 seconds, then it powers back up and goes to the lock screen.

This is the output of `systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block`:

```
WHO     UID  USER    PID  COMM           WHAT                                                     WHY                                                         MODE 
michael 1000 michael 2399 gsd-power      handle-lid-switch                                        External monitor attached or configuration changed recently block
michael 1000 michael 2398 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key GNOME handling keypresses                                   block
```

Notables:

- I have my laptop lid closed, and plug in an external monitor
- I have played with various power settings, tried various combinations of lid, screen diming, and power button settings.
- I have a disabled radeon graphics card `sudo nvim /etc/default/grub` contains (`radeon.modeset=0`):

  ```
  RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0card)
  ```
- Have gone through the BIOS and disabled all `wake from` options, e.g wake from USB/LAN/AC etc.

Comment: Freaky, I have the same problem and my name is also Michael :-D

Answer (score 3):

I found this behavior was caused by an nvidia driver upgrade not removing some broken symlinks as outlined here:
[Ubuntu 20.04 suspend logs off and wakes up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391976/ubuntu-20-04-suspend-logs-off-and-wakes-up)

Even though I get similar output as you above, it was not related to the issue and I can now suspend after removing the broken links.

Comment: yes. the linked answer is working like a charm!